# Maxima, Alternator & AC

Tags: ac, nissan, alternator, maxima

2007 Nissan Maxima just came out of the shop for alternator replacement 2 hours ago. The AC worked great when it went in and now it blows hot.

Question is- could it be anything more than bad timing?

Comment: Check the belts at the front of the engine - make sure the alternator belt is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They probably didn't recharge the system when they were done, check your invoice. Another possibility is that they forgot to plug the compressor clutch back in. You need to remove the A/C compressor when you R&R the alternator on the 3.5. There are ways around having to discharge the A/C like letting it hang and working around the lines, but it's easier to just discharge and remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Returned the maxima to the shop to have them correct it and they said that when they removed the radiator to replace the alternator a connector line came loose for the ac.  Problem Resolved....but now there is a tapping or knocking that still knocks at idle and speeds up while moving. It sounds as if a fan blade is hitting something but I don't see anything. Ughhhh.